# File name during import/export of Sqlite Db Android

Tags: java, android

In my application  i have  used import and export backup functionality but every time its replace with old file because of static path ? so how can i resolve this issue

--> Export on  SD card

```
public void exportDB(){
    try {

        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        if (sd.canWrite()) {
            String currentDBPath = "data/data/com.example.mybudget/databases/MyBudget.db";
            String backupDBPath = sd + "/MyBudget.db";
            File currentDB = new File(currentDBPath);
            File backupDB = new File(backupDBPath);

            if(sd.exists())
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Backup Exists Woult you like to Replace ?", 1000).show();
            }
            if (currentDB.exists()) {
                FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());

                src.close();
                dst.close();
                }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

-----> Import from SD card

```
public void importDB(){
    try {
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        if (sd.canWrite()) {
            String currentDBPath = sd + "/MyBudget.db";
            String backupDBPath = "data/data/com.example.mybudget/databases/MyBudget.db";
            File currentDB = new File(currentDBPath);
            File backupDB = new File(backupDBPath);

            if (currentDB.exists()) {
                FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                src.close();
                dst.close();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by static path ?

Comment: path that stored in string variable String path= "sdcard/MyBudget.db";

Comment: irrelevant title, just asked to rename file during import export

Comment: Hey do you know how to keep same size of data in listview ?

Comment: this is another question, ask a new question. thanks

Comment: in Listview data is not display in proepr format .

Comment: i have used Linear Layout

Answer (score 0):

You can add the date to a file name, like so:

```
private static final String DATE_FORMAT_NOW = "yyyyMMddHHmmss";

private String now() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT_NOW);
    return sdf.format(cal.getTime());
}

(...)

String backupDBPath = sd + "/MyBudget-"+now()+".db";
```

To retrieve last file only get the first file when sorting files by date (new to old) or by name (because date is in name).

Comment: But What when the time of importing ?

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand you

Comment: First Thank You for your Wonderful help . by this i am able to create a new instance of backup file . but suppose when i create one account name home_data i am exporting now database and than delete database . i am creating one new account office_data now again i am exporting data . but this time it only import the file which i export the first time . it will import home_data backup file  but what if i want to get office_data backup file ?